# Morph floating action button into related actions

Tags: android, animation, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I would like to morph the floating action button into related actions after it is first touched. If one of these buttons gets clicked the corresponding action will be performed and the buttons morph back to the single floating action button. If you touch anywhere else on the screen, no action will be performed and the buttons morph back to the single floating action button.

Lets image the example of a simple editor, that implements an action button to create a new file. Clicking this action button should morph this button into three different buttons, which let me choose one of three file types to create. This behavior is description in Google's material design specification, but I cannot find an example implementation, that helps me getting started.

Comment: Something like a `FloatingActionMenu` containing multiple `FloatingActionButton` https://github.com/sephiroth74/android-floating-action-menu

Comment: Thanks for sharing this Link, but i was watching for a horizontal solutions without adding another (not yet complete) library. However, i was now able to create a new Layout holding the three buttons, so I just need to fade/morph on button click into this new layout. Any hints here how I should do this?

Answer (score 1):

I personally used [futuresimple's android-floating-action-button](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/tree/master/library/src/main/java/com/getbase/floatingactionbutton) to make 2 java class that handles all that.

It supports the four expand directions:

```
public static final int EXPAND_UP = 0;
public static final int EXPAND_DOWN = 1;
public static final int EXPAND_LEFT = 2;
public static final int EXPAND_RIGHT = 3;
```

You can add his library or just copy its few java class. Really minimal code and working great.

Or just look at how he animates things (from `FloatingActionMenu.java`).