# Alternative to using multiple FloatingActionButtons?

Tags: android, button, material-design, floating-action-button

Right now I am using three FloatingActionButtons to represent add, save, and reset operations. However according to Material Design guidelines, you shouldn't use more than one such button: https://material.google.com/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html

What is the accepted practice? Is there another sort of bar that is better for holding onto multiple functionality buttons?

Comment: Just the main action should be in a FloatingActionButton, probably save in your case. You can place the rest in a menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a single action button that transforms into related actions, i.e., add, save and reset. 
So you'll have something like this after the floating action button was pressed: [image: Example of floating action button transformed into related actions]

If you choose to do this you might want to check out this:
[Morph floating action button into related actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050779/morph-floating-action-button-into-related-actions)

Another option could be transforming the floating action button into a toolbar like this:

[image: floating action button transformed into toolbar]

In that case you will want to check this out:
 [Floating Action Button expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678675/floating-action-button-expansion)